Replacement handbrake release cable "hook" catching its frame on Ford S-Max '08
I have just bought a new replacement cable for my Ford S-Max duratorq '08 as my handbrake release cable snapped. I fitted it and gave it a quick tug to try it out, but it wouldn't work properly - It wouldn't release the handbrake. It would begin to release, then stop.
I quickly figured out it wouldn't work because the hook is smaller and more importantly, the "sleeve" part of the hook, the bit that holds it to the wire, is shorter (the hook feels like die-cast, btw, so probably a bit brittle). This shortness is causing it to get caught on the handbrake frame. The cable travels through a piece of U-shaped frame, and the hook is getting caught on the bottom of the "U". I hope you get me here... if not, some pictures should help!
This is the hook at the end of the cable (at the bottom). That is the cog on the right. When you pull the cable from the left of this picture, the hook pulls the metal "stopper" piece which pivots at that silver thing, rotating the stopper away from the cog teeth, allowing the cog to rotate as you release the handbrake (Down). If you didn't know, this part of the handbrake is what clicks like a ratchet when you pull the handbrake up (On).

But, what I call the "sleeve", which is the start of the hook, is getting caught on the frame when pulled left, stopping it from releasing the cog properly. If I push the hook up, moving the "sleeve" above the "U" frame, it works.

This is the OLD hook, which seems to have hit the frame quite hard itself, at least once, possibly when I was trying to release the handbrake to get the car home (there is a dent just after the sleeve part), before I had proper access to the handbrake unit (you can release it by hand using the spring holder at the top of the "stopper" piece in the first pic if you have access). Note the longer sleeve on this old hook and also note that it is thicker, at about 3-4mm compared to the replacement which is about 2mm (diameter).

So now you know exactly what my issue is, my question should be obvious and relatively simple!
How can I stop it from catching the frame?
Ideally, I won't have to remove the handbrake unit because that looks like a big job!!
